# Our house is made of sugar

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Can you explain to me please. What do you mean, when to talk "Our house is made of sugar."?

Comment: Where have you heard this expression? I would never _say_ (not talk) it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I learn English and I heard this interesting suggestion at duolingo.

Comment: My guess is that one good rain will dissolve it and there will be no house left, but you should [edit] your question to explain more about the situation where you heard it.

Comment: Is it from a fairy tale?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the queried text ("Our house is made of sugar") has no idiomatically established meaning, so without a *specific* context it's impossible to say what it means.

Comment: I found a short story called [*The House Made of Sugar*](https://longreads.com/2015/02/14/the-house-made-of-sugar/), which includes the text: *If other people lived in this house, they must have been like those sugar figurines on desserts, or birthday cakes: sweet as sugar. **This house makes me feel secure*** (emphasis mine). Perhaps OP is quoting someone who expects his readers to pick up on that allusion *(Our house feels very safe)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A house made of sugar* is not an established idiom. If someone said it I would assume they mean their house is delicate and perhaps prone to dissolving in the rain, as Colleen mentioned.

But there is [a proverb](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/people+who+live+in+glass+houses+shouldn%27t+throw+stones):

> People who live in **glass houses** shouldn't throw stones.

This means that someone who has some fault, and is liable to be criticized for it, should not criticize someone else for having that same fault—because it invites attention and criticism back on themselves. The metaphor is someone living in a glass house who throws a stone at another person; the stone is likely to break the house.

Is it possible this context is close to what Duolingo suggested?

Comment: From a search, it appears to be a literal translation of an idiom or saying from another language, but the author really should clarify the context.

Comment: @ColleenV
There is no context. Just a suggestion "Our house is made of sugar."

Comment: A suggestion of what @VladimirGlinskikh? It looks like a discussion of a translation to me. https://forum-duolingo-com.translate.goog/comment/35253360/Our-house-is-made-of-sugar?_x_tr_sl=be&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=ajax,nv,elem